# Changing background image opacity while not affecting opacity of the containing div

Tags: html, css

My question is: If I have set a background image on a div in CSS, can I set the opacity of that image using CSS only, while not affecting the opacity of the div itself? I use multiple backgrounds so doing it HTML would be complicated, so I only want a CSS solution (if possible).

Comment: `opacity: your desired level;`

Comment: You cannot set the opacity of a 'background'. What you CAN do is use a background **color** which has some opacity using either RGBA or HSLA.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, I know that, but I want to have a background image with opacity less than 1

Comment: You cannot do that with a background image.

Comment: well, that's sad... are you absolutely sure?

Comment: Absolutely. You will need to use stacked elements or try changing the image in an image editor such as Photoshop.

Comment: Yes, that would be logical, but if I changed the background image, I would have to redo that work in Photoshop

Comment: You can't change opacity on a `background-image`, background opacity is only possible with `rgba()` colors.  But you can always edit the image itself and give it an alpha channel (e.g. make it a png).  Or you can restructure your markup/css and make the background a real `img` and set the `opacity` on that.

Comment: @AttilaHerbert yes, no matter what you're going to have to either redo work in PS or redo work in markup/CSS, so what?  Also it takes 2 minutes to modify opacity of an image in PS...

Comment: yes, I know, but if you have ever managed a site with changing backgrounds, you know it is a pain in the a$$.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YrGRz/3/

Comment: I edited your answer for clarity's sake, it could have easily been misconstrued before. In regards to your question, disregarding mituw16's answer, are the answer's below not working? It seems to me there were 2 answers provided that use CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this with CSS:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/The_sun1.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wnRy/

Answer (score 0):

```
opacity : 0.2;
filter: alpha(opacity=20); /*ie*/
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YrGRz/3/

Comment: Unfortunately not, he's trying to affect a background image in CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D According to the question title he is.

Comment: Then what is trying to be accomplished? The question asks about background opacity?

Comment: You cannot affect the opacity of background images with CSS

Comment: @mituw16 he is asking about `background-image` property in conjunction with CSS `opacity` (which is not possible) so your answer isn't applicable.

Comment: You can apply opacity to the background image of a <div> when the image is applied so: background:url('my_image.png')

Comment: @PeteR No, you can't.  You can apply opacity to the entire `div` but not solely to the `background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate this by using a pseudo element.

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
}

div::after {
    content: "";
    opacity: .3;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url("background-image.png");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lrsbck/aEhgs/